# New group in New column

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a multi column report in crystal report.Is there any way to start each new group in new column in Crystal report in the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, and it's very easy when you know how!**

If you create an empty group footer for the column and in the section expert tick 'Print at Bottom of Page' this will force the next group into the next column.

When you create a grouping, by default, there will also be an empty footer created; if, in design mode, you right click the group descriptions for this footer on the left (or Select Reports -> Section Expert from the menu at the top) and select Section Expert, hightlight the group footer on the left hand list in the Section Expert dialog, on the right you should be able to click the option 'Print at Bottom of Page'

This will force the column to print an empty footer at the bottom of the page, and the next column must come afte the previous groups footer, hence it will appear in the next column.

Does that help?

**If you also need the footer to appear immediately at the bottom of the column** you can create two footers [from the Section Expert click insert button when you've got the single footer selected] set the second one (#B) to be very thin, it actually has to have some height or CR wont print it, but make it very thin and select the Print at bottom option,  and all should be well.  You can put any summary or labels in the other (#A) footer.

Comment: Hello I have two groups and none of the group footer is empty. So what happens is that it keeps some blank spaces between two groups whenever there is not enough data to fill the whole page. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure but for each section you can actually add multiples, for example from the Section Expert if you click on the group footer and click the insert button (at the top there.) you'll have group footer A & B. put your totals in A and set B to 'Print at Bottom of Page? will that help..?

Comment: you have two groupings do you want a new column after the second grouping? and do you have anything in the footer for each grouping?