# Reporting Services 2005: Group into columns

Tags: reporting-services

From a query, I get these results:

```
Machine 1, Product A, 1 pal  
Machine 1, Product B, 2 pal  
Machine 1, Product C, 3 pal  
Machine 2, Product D, 2 pal  
Machine 2, Product E, 2 pal  
Machine 3, Product F, 1 pal
```

I would like to create a report that looks like this:

```
Machine 1  |  Machine 2  |  Machine 3 
Product A  |  Product D  |  Product F  
1 pal      |    2 pal    | 1 pal  
Product B  |  Product E  |   
2 pal      |  2 pal  
Product C
3 pal
```

I know above formatting sucks but it gives an idea. I guess this is the same problem as in [New group in New column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987419/new-group-in-new-column) but with another technology. Is anyone able to help? Would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way of achieving this using SSRS `Matrix` report item in conjunction with SQL Server `ROW_NUMBER` function. Following example shows how this can be done. The example uses **`SSRS 2005`** with **`SQL Server 2008 R2`** database.

**Step-by-step process:** `SSRS 2005`

1. Created a table named `dbo.GroupColumns` representing the data that you provided as shown in screenshot #**1**. Create scripts of the table is provided under SQL Scripts section.
2. Created a query shown in screenshot #**2**, which will be used to create the SSRS dataset. Query is provided under **SSRS dataset query** section. Screenshot #**2** shows the query output in Management Studio. The query uses `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign sequential numbers within a given `Machine` sorted by `Machine` and `Product`.
3. On the SSRS Report, place a `Matrix` report item. Refer screenshot #**3**.
4. Drag and drop `RowRank`, `Machine` and `Product` values from the data set onto the Matrix as shown in screenshot #**4**.
5. Right-click on the cell containing Product value and select **Add Row** as shown in screenshot #**5**. A new second column will be added along with a new row.
6. Drag and drop the `Units` column from data set onto the Matrix as shown in screenshot #**6**.
7. Set the **Width** property on the **second** matrix column to `0 (zero)` because we don't want to show that column. Even though it is set to zero, the value will change to `0.03125 in`. Screenshot #**7** shows the Matrix report item after applying some formatting and coloring.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupColumns](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Machine] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Units] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupColumns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**SSRS dataset query:**

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY    Machine 
            ORDER BY        Machine
                        ,   Product
        ) AS RowRank
    ,   Id
    ,   Machine
    ,   Product
    ,   Units 
FROM    dbo.GroupColumns
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

Comment: Great, this solved the problem! Adding the rownumber as a group did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Had to give this a vote up for detail alone, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can achieve this using the Matrix control. Just place the Machine Field in the column group and then just place the product and pal fields in the details group. You can just stub the row group with "=1" in your expression.

Comment: Getting close but not quite right yet. If I group by "=1", only the first row gets displayed. If I group by "=RowNumber(Nothing)", all data gets displayed but there are gaps in the matrix, eg. [link](http://imgur.com/g7d8D)